# Enumerating the square equivalent classes

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, group-actions, integer-lattices

Fill the $n\times n$ lattice square with natural numbers $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ each of which is used exactly $n$ times. Two configurations are in an equivalence class if and only if one is transformed from the other by any of the following group actions.

1. A permutation of the numbers.
2. Rotations of integer multiples of $\frac\pi 2$ about the axis perpendicular to the plane the square resides on.
3. Reflection about vertical, horizontal and diagonal axises of the square.

How many equivalence classes of the configurations are there? What if we roll the square into a torus?

---

Do I need to apply [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma)?

To start with, $n=3$.

Comment: Might this be about 'integer-lattices'? Doesn't seem to be about 'lattice-orders'.

Comment: @amrsa: Corrected.